# CORS issue with react and django-rest-framework

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, create-react-app

I'm using react on the frontend side and Django on the backend. I using `django-cors-headers`
for managing CORS in my Django app.

I have added the package in `INSTALLED_APPS` like this:-

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'services',
    'feeds',
    'knox',
    'users',
]
```

then I have also added same in `MIDDLEWARE`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

and I'm passing CORS headers from my **client-side** React app like:-

```
const Axios = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${BASE_URL}/api`,
    timeout: 1000,

    headers: { 
        'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
     }  
})
```

Error on frontend:-

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: and the error you get is?

Comment: I'm getting this error on my frontend console
```Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a bug in my client-side headers`'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar',` after removing it started working fine

Answer (score 0):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is sent by server, not by frontend. Server also does not send this header always. Whenever client sends origin header, only then server sends Access-Control-Allow-Origin and when origin is not matched, CORS error in thrown. If you used create-react-app to bootstrap your react project, they have really nice documentation how to configure [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/), that way you dont have to configure CORS on backend. In django configuration try to remove *ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']* line, *CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True* should work for all.

Comment: Hi @gautamits, thanks for response. I tried removing ``` ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] ```
still getting CORS error in my frontend. Also, I went through the documentation proxy documentation for CRA, it will only work for a development server. I need to this for both development and production

Comment: Please try hitting your api with CURL with *Origin* header. Check if server is really sending any *Access-Control-Allow-Origin*.