# React to django CORS issue

Tags: python, reactjs, django, python-3.9

**Error Details**

[image]

Two requests have been generating on button click.

**What did I search so far?**

[Axios blocked by CORS policy with Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55366740/axios-blocked-by-cors-policy-with-django-rest-framework)

[CORS issue with react and django-rest-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61444853/cors-issue-with-react-and-django-rest-framework?rq=1)

but to no avail

**What am I doing?**

Submitting POST request from react to DJango API

**Django side settings file**

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000", 
    "http://127.0.0.1", 
    "http://localhost:3000", 
    "http://localhost"
]
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000", 
    "http://127.0.0.1", 
    "http://localhost:3000", 
    "http://localhost"
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ......,
    "corsheaders"
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    .........,
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
```

**React axios request**

```
function authenticate() {
    let body = {
        "email": "ac",
        "password": "def"
    };
    const headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/", body, {
        headers: headers
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**Tried another approach using fetch, but to no avail**

```
function authenticate() {
    let body = {
        "email": "hi",
        "password": "pass"
    };
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/login", {
        method: "POST", 
        headers: { 
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

DJango side method

```
def Login(request):
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        return JsonResponse({"message" : "Invalid credentials"}, status=401)
```

Comment: Try adding CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False in your settings file

Comment: try to add the cors middleware in the first place of your middleware array and give me feedback about it, thanks

Comment: Does `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True` do anything if everything else is commented out?

Comment: no change took place. same error. Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below settings work for me

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "127.0.0.1", 
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1", 
]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .....
    "corsheaders"
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    ......
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Damn, I was going to suggest replacing the "whitelist" field with the updated one and removing the protocol from the allowed_hosts.  BTW, you should try setting `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False` to make sure that your allowed origins setting works properly.

Comment: Everything works perfectly with this setting.

Comment: Please add a description of changes that has been made to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens because of the url pattern. Please check the url pattern whether it requires a slash at the end or not.

Try using `'login'` instead of `'login/'`

Comment: Same error coming. No changes after removing forward slash at end.

Comment: this was the error for me. I had a CORS issue without the final slash, and adding it solved it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your server endpoints online accessible for your ReactJS application then you should try to set this in Django `settings.py` file

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:portNum',
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

# Any headers you wanted to be visible by the ReactJS app.
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = [
    'Date'
]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, you forgot to provide "mode": "cors" for your requests, didn't you?
And you have to process on server side "OPTIONS" requests made by browser in Preflight phase.

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header should be sent by server in response. You don't need it in request.

Read a good explanation on "CORS" requests here: https://javascript.info/fetch-crossorigin

And to correctly setup Django read this: [How can I enable CORS on Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework)

Comment: added method defined django side, how should I return Access-Control-Allow-Origin as response?

Comment: I'm not professional with Django, but looks like it is handled by `django-cors-headers` lib automatically

Answer (score -1):

Try removing `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`. Just keep `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`.
This is my setting on real server:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
  'accept',
  'accept-encoding',
  'authorization',
  'content-type',
  'origin',
  'dnt',
  'user-agent',
  'x-csrftoken',
  'x-requested-with']
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ['DELETE', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'PUT']
```